# can not sudo to root in Ubuntu instance

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo

I have an error when i want to become root

```
╭─saviam@server ~ 
╰─$ sudo -i                                                                                                                                                                                           
   sudo: myPassword*: command not found
╭─saviam@server ~ 
╰─$
```

Comment: What's the content of `/etc/passwd`? Does `sudo /bin/bash` work?

Comment: Do `sudo su -` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `sudo: myPassword*: command not found` can occur due to 2 different reasons:

1. The `PATH` variable for user does not contains the path to `sudo` binary.
2. `sudo` package was mistakenly removed from the server.

**Solution for reason 1:**

- Check for the absolute path for `sudo` binary using command `find /usr/bin/ /bin/ /usr/local/bin/ /sbin/ -type f -name sudo`
- You can use the the absolute path to run the sudo command, like `/usr/bin/sudo -i` , However this is temporary fix.
- As a permanent fix, you need to add the absolute path of the `sudo` binary to user `saviam`'s `PATH` variable.
- Run command `echo 'PATH="sudo_absolute_path:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc` replacing `sudo_absolute_path` with actual path to `sudo` binary. It should be like `/usr/bin` or `/bin` etc.

**Solution for reason 2:**

- If `sudo` package is missing from the server, you will need to install the package back.
- For this, you will need to login with user `root` and install the package.

Comment: Thanks. The sudo binary path was missing from `PATH` variable. The solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

I just confirmed, since I have the same issue.  For ubuntu:22.04_stable since you are root I guess they decided to not install the package.

apt install sudo

This fixed the issues for me.

Comment: This answer is already given by the previous answer.